# Regex to check for bind parameters NOT in quotes

Tags: regex, ruby

I currently have a regex that is detecting for binded parameters in SQL statements as follows

```
/(:?):([a-zA-Z]\w*)/
```

- `WHERE id = :id and productcode = :product_code`

  - Match `:id` and `:product_code`
- `WHERE id = :id and productcode = '1:2 :3'`

  - Match `:id` only
- `WHERE id = :id and code LIKE 'string with:colon and :bind_parameters' OR product_name LIKE :product_name'`

  - Match `:id` and `:product_name`
- `SELECT :id and :product_code WHERE id = 2 and product_code = 3`

  - Match `:id` and `:product_code`

So any matches that I get with my current regex, I need to check if they are surrounded in quotes to reject them. Not too familiar with regex, but is there any way to modify my current regex to check if the bind parameters is not surrounded in quotes and is its own individual word?

Comment: You should give example strings that should match and shouldn't match. It's unclear to me what you're looking for. For example, your failure case produces `#<MatchData ":ProductName" 1:"" 2:"ProductName">`. Why is that a failure? What did you want instead?

Comment: @Kache Right, I've updated the post with matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all single quoted strings and match and *capture* the required pattern in all other contexts. After getting the results, flatten the list and remove `nil` values to get a clean result:

```
strings = [ "WHERE id = :id and productcode = :product_code", "WHERE id = :id and productcode = '1:2 :3'","WHERE id = :id and code LIKE 'string with:colon and :bind_parameters' OR product_name LIKE :product_name'","SELECT :id and :product_code WHERE id = 2 and product_code = 3" ]
strings.each { |x| 
  puts "#{x} =>"
  p x.scan(/'(?:[^']|'')*'|\B(:\w+)/).flatten.compact
}
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/DKycfj)

The `nil` values appear when the first alternative matches, but since `.scan` only returns captured values and the capturing group does not match in case the first alternative "wins", the `nil` is added to the result.

**Pattern details**:

- `'` - a `'` char
- `(?:[^']|'')*` - any zero or more chars other than `'` or double `'` char
- `'` - a `'` char
- `|` - or
- `\B(:\w+)` -  a non-word boundary and then `:` and one or more letters, digits, `_`s.

Output of the above demo:

```
WHERE id = :id and productcode = :product_code =>
[":id", ":product_code"]
WHERE id = :id and productcode = '1:2 :3' =>
[":id"]
WHERE id = :id and code LIKE 'string with:colon and :bind_parameters' OR product_name LIKE :product_name' =>
[":id", ":product_name"]
SELECT :id and :product_code WHERE id = 2 and product_code = 3 =>
[":id", ":product_code"]
```

Comment: This is great, allows me to continue forward. I'm using gsub instead of scan so I'll just have some conditional to check for quotes and skip if need be. Thanks! Just one more question, how would you modify something like this to skip escaped quotes? Something like 
`'string/'s with:colon and :bind_parameters'`

Comment: @RyanTin It is a very well-known construct to match single quoted C string literals: `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` with `/m` flag (to make `.` match line break chars). Replace `'(?:[^']|'')*'` with it. I just thought your quoted strings can have `'` quoted with another `'`, as in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples:

```rb
strings = [
  "WHERE id = :id and productcode = :product_code",
  "WHERE id = :id and productcode = '1:2 :3'",
]

strings.map { |s| s.scan(/= (:\w+?)\b/).flatten }
# => [[":id", ":product_code"], [":id"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but there there might be other operators other than `=` use sometime, and sometimes it might even show up in the SELECT query as well. I've updated my question to be clearer.