# Regex to replace bind parameters that NOT in quotes

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I have a regex that detects text in quotes (first group) and bind parameters (second group).
Group for text in quotes is required to avoid replacing bind parameters in it.

```
('[^\\n']*')|(:\\s*\\w+)
```

I tried to keep first group and replace second one with "?":

```
public static String replaceBindVars(String value) {
    return value.replaceAll("('[^\\n']*')|(:\\s*\\w+)", "$1?"); 
}
```

The problem is that it adds "?" after first group.

Code to test, the result should be true in all cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("WHERE id = ? and productcode = ?"
            .equals(replaceBindVars("WHERE id = :id and productcode = :product_code")));
    
    System.out.println("WHERE id = ? and productcode = '1:2 :3'"
            .equals(replaceBindVars("WHERE id = :id and productcode = '1:2 :3'")));
    
    System.out.println("WHERE id = ? and code LIKE ': some-string with :colon and :bind_parameters' OR product_name LIKE ?'".
            equals(replaceBindVars("WHERE id = :id and code LIKE ': some-string with :colon and :bind_parameters' OR product_name LIKE :product_name'")));
    
    System.out.println("SELECT ? and ? WHERE id = 2 and product_code = 3".
            equals(replaceBindVars("SELECT :id and :product_code WHERE id = 2 and product_code = 3")));
    
}
```

Is there any way to modify my current regex to do not add "?" after bind parameters in quotes? Preferred Java version is 8.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64083453/4885272) similar question, but it doesn't help.

Comment: the problem isn't with the regex but with the replacment. Just use two distinct regexs and that'll solve your problem

Comment: @Aaron, but I don't understand how to avoide replacement of bind parameters in quotes if it will be distinct regexs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable replacement with [*`public String replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
public static final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("('[^\\n']*')|:\\s*\\w+");
public static String replaceBindVars(String value) {
    return regex.matcher(value).replaceAll(m -> m.group(1) != null ? m.group(1) : "?"); 
}
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/Y0Kj8A).

If Group 1 matches, Group 1 value is output (no change is made), else, the match is replaced with a `?` char (this way, there is no need in Group 2).

In Java 8 and older versions you can use

```java
public static final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("('[^\\n']*')|:\\s*\\w+");
public static String replaceBindVars(String value) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(value);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            m.appendReplacement(result, Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group(1)));
        } else {
            m.appendReplacement(result, "?");
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    return result.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks! it really works. I've also tried to use matcher but didn't manage to. But is there a way to do this in Java 8?